# CKAN persona sessions conflict after username update

Tags: python, python-2.7, session, session-variables, ckan

I try to use ckanext-persona (https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-persona) for my custom CKAN login. 
In first All goes well:
Successfully register new account, so i have some random name user loged-in with my current email. But when i try change user name to more humanize (default is something like `a6f282c6-4c5a-4467-a541-c51fc21e4a4fs`) strange thinks happens:

1. Right after i push "update profile" button i got redirect to `http://localhost/user/new_user_name?__no_cache__=True` with Error 500 on this page. And my user is not logged in visually. Full error log https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wide-awake/a80143d5cb4f333a524b/raw/b1af1d82a583863de9d636e868ac808bbc0b0ba6/ckan-persona_username_update_errror
2. Next, If i press "login" i got usual login page,  but with messege `"You're already logged in as a6f282c6-4c5a-4467-a541-c51fc21e4a4f. Logout?"`
3. If i press "Logout" on this message guess what? System log me out and i automatically appear logged in as `new_user_name`.

I think session with old username was not destroyed when i update profile. Can you point me in right direction?

Also every time i hit logout (from any user) i got "logout failed" popup right before usual `You are now logged out`.

Comment: I got comment from @rossjones at CKAN IRC: If I had to guess I'd think it'd be something around https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-persona/blob/master/ckanext/persona/plugin.py#L70 and https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-persona/blob/master/ckanext/persona/plugin.py#L81

Comment: @rossjones: I think it's a but - the IAuthenticator isn't called when user_update is processed to log the user out - so the session is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I've supplied a fix for this (along with prettier usernames) at https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-persona/pull/3 and https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-persona/pull/5

Pending review, it should be good to go.

If you installed with git clone, you can test them both out individually by doing

`git fetch
git checkout 2-use-id-in-session
or 
git checkout 4-prettier-usernames`

If I get positive feedback, I'll merge them.